# Why does Windows 8.1. allege that 'this DVD-ROM drive is read-only', when it's not?

Tags: windows-8.1, dvd, burning

I've 2 kinds of blank DVD-RWs: Sony ("S" henceforth), and Memorex ("M"). I performed everything on the same computer and DVD drive. When I tried to write files to a blank M using only Windows (no software), the burning stopped and this message arose:

> This DVD-ROM drive is read only. You can copy files to this writable DVD,  you must insert it into a writable drive.

But I successfully burned a S, before this attempt with M. So I removed this interrupted M, and tried to burn another S, that did burn successfully. Then [I reattempted to burn M](https://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/microsoft-windows/threads/460071/dvd-burner-error-message#post1999838), and the error message overhead reappeared. Are all M discs corrupt? How can I check this, before discarding them all?

Answer (score 0):

RW media are tricky. First, they say they take speeds "up to", but in my experience slow and easy does it. Set up the write speed as slow as possible. You may need some burning software for that, as MS built-in can be spotty. I am unsure whether MS's built-in allows selection of write speed.

Secondly: unfortunately producing reliable RW requires good manufacture. I never had problems with Sony RWs, but Verbatim/Memorex/previously-unknown-MFR had their issues. This may be media issue, so I would RTS'd them. I personally stick to TDK's as they ALWAYS come through. Admittedly, I've dropped RW in favour of USB's/email/cloud, so now basically just Rs. But they are in data media like Canon is in printing (pop it in and it works).

Thirdly: whenever possible, I'm using +R/RW instead of -R/RW. I've found it much more stable and reliable, with much fewer issues during and after writing,  and then later use.

Last thing: how old is the burner itself? Current crop of drives are pretty reliable up to one year with normal use, after that beam power drops significantly, causing issues exactly like this.

**Update: I just remembered that RW does not like exposure to strong light, especially sunlight. It has to do with technology. I had several going bad after checking them for scratches against window in summer/ strong sunlight.**

Comment: +1. Thanks. 1. What does RTS stand for, in your para 2? 2. I answer your second-last paragraph: The burner is the one on my laptop, which is only around 8 months old.

Comment: RTS = Return To Seller (Sender). 2. 8 months is not that much. I personally used 7-year old burner without issues. I should actually edit answer, as writing that one year for burner is bad is rather silly of me. However rest stands: laser gets weaker with time, but it has often more to do with lens getting dirty than use-up.

Comment: I guess it also depends on how much you use it, not merely on time. My old PlexWriter worked perfectly for 10+ years, but I burned fewer than 10 discs per year.